# error "Thread 1: EXC_BAD_INSTRUCTION (code=EXC_I386_INVOP, subcode=0x0)"

Tags: arrays, swift, swiftui, crash

This is my code

```
import UIKit

struct Hero {
    let name: String
    let image: UIImage
    let type: String
    let skinimage: [UIImage]
   // let intro: String
}

var heros: [Hero] = [ 
    Hero(name: "abc", image: #imageLiteral(resourceName: "abc.jpg"), type: "red",skinimage: [#imageLiteral(resourceName: "abca.jpg")]),
    Hero(name: "aaa", image: #imageLiteral(resourceName: "aaa.jpg"), type: "blue",skinimage:[ #imageLiteral(resourceName: "aaaa.jpg")]),
    Hero(name: "123", image: #imageLiteral(resourceName: "123.jpg"), type: "green",skinimage: [#imageLiteral(resourceName: "123a.jpg")]),
    Hero(name: "456", image: #imageLiteral(resourceName: "456.jpg"), type: "red",skinimage: [#imageLiteral(resourceName: "456a.jpg")])
]
```

There is an error

> "Thread 1: EXC_BAD_INSTRUCTION (code=EXC_I386_INVOP, subcode=0x0)"

on name: "abc".

Also, `heros` array has no value. I think it is a crash.

I want to fix it and know how to that.

Comment: Have you double checked that the resources exists and are spelled correctly?

Answer (score 0):

In your initializers, instead of

```
#imageLiteral(resourceName: "abc.jpg")
```

use

```
UIImage(named: “abc.jpg”)
```

For example:

```
    Hero(name: "abc", image: UIImage(named: “abc.jpg”), type: "red",skinimage: [UIImage(named: “abca.jpg”)]),
```